# Using a Virtual Machine for Active Directory for application development

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, virtual-machines, testing, virtualization

I'm developing a .NET application which requires user authentication and role management to happen through Active Directory. I was wondering whether there was a way of installing a test instance of AD on a Virtual Machine (have Windows Server 2003 through Virtual PC) and connecting from my desktop environment to the VM AD instance?

I have tried AD LDS and ADAM on my local desktop, and for whatever reason kept encountering problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you building a virtual machine that is a Domain Controller and is isolated from the rest of your network.

AD LDS/ADAM (they're the same thing - ADAM is the 2003 name, AD LDS the 2008 equivalent) is not the same as having an Active Directory domain.